# API call in NextJS getStaticProps causes error 500

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

An API call made in `getStaticProps` seems to cause an error 500.

Here's my component's code:

```js
import React from "react";
import API from "services/api";

const ArtistListPage = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {props.artists.map((artist) => (
                <div key={artist.id}>{artist.first_name}</div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
    // Get external data from the file system, API, DB, etc.
    const res = await API.get("/get_artists");
    const artists = await res.data.json();
    return {
        props: { artists },
    };
}

export default ArtistListPage;
```

I'd like to mention that the same API call in a `useEffect` works, as well as passing in a hard coded object to `props` in `getStaticProps`. Only the API call inside the `getStaticProps` seems  to cause an issue.

Does anyone know where the error could come from and how to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getStaticProps` is executed at a build time and you can't call your own API because Next.js server is not running.

You can execute DB queries or read from file system inside `getStaticProps` directly, without making an API call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't really get how I'm supposed to make my page SEO friendly if it depends of data queried from the database... Am I supposed to use `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen, it depends on nature of the data. If it doesn't change often you can consider pre-render it at build time. `getServerSideProps ` will fetch data on every request and pre-render it on the server side but the request time would increase as it's no longer statically rendered.

Comment: Even with a `getServerSideProps`, I am still getting that error 500... Any idea why and how I can fix that?

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen, you can check Node.js console output in CLI / logs to see the exact error that caused error 500.